# Foreach control item in panel not selecting all items

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, collections

My problem is that i've got a panel called PanelNewFriend, where i'm dynamically creating buttons from all users from a mysql database. So when someone clicks on a user and sends an invite , what should be happening is that it should remove all buttons (Except for the back button which has a tag of "1") and then place all the buttons again for the new list of all users.

When creating the buttons i assigned a tag with value "0" to them. All buttons have it even though i don't think the problem lies in the tag.

I'm using this code to remove all buttons in the panel.

```
foreach (Button item in PanelNewFriend.Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            if (item.Tag == "0")
            {
                PanelNewFriend.Controls.Remove(item);
            }
        }
```

I've tried multiple things, ranging from foreach Control item  and oftype Control. To changing the item.Tag != "1" and item.Tag == "". None of this worked

**But** when i actually execute the code and add breaking points I can see that there are 4 buttons in the panel. But when i go through each foreach cycle, it only selects 2 of the 4 buttons. So since it only selects 2 buttons it is only deleting 2 and leaving the other 2 alone.

Any idea what could be causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic collection modification problem here. You're modifying the collection as you're iterating over it. That will result in unexpected behavior. Ideally you should be getting `InvalidOperationException` but sadly `ControlCollection` doesn't implement this check.

You have two options. Either take a copy of the collection and iterate over the copy or use a reverse for loop.

```
var buttonsToRemove = PanelNewFriend.Controls
                                .OfType<Button>()
                                .Where(x=> x.Tag == "0")
                                .ToArray();//Take a copy

foreach (Button item in buttonsToRemove)
{
    PanelNewFriend.Controls.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I was baffeled as i've been using this for a few things in my project and it never failed me. I see what was going wrong now thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
List<Button> removeList = new List<Button>();
foreach (Button item in PanelNewFriend.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
  if (item.Tag == "0")
  {
    removeList.Add(item);
  }
}
foreach (Button item in removeList)
  PanelNewFriend.Controls.Remove(item);
```

Comment: Thanks but Sriram already gave the same solution in bit cleaner and easier to understand snippet.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. When you say try like this, you could try to explain what was the problem also, otherwise it won't help for OP as well as future readers. Btw good start. +1